# Is it possible to somehow make the text that is written in the <li> tag to the left of the markers?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

this is my first question on stackoverflow.com, sorry if that.
My problem is that I can't make the text that is written in the `<li>` tag to the left of the markers.

```css
.stages{
    list-style-type: none; 
    counter-reset: num;
    margin: 0 0 0 45px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.stages__working{
    position: relative; 
    margin: 0 ;
    padding: 8px 0 45px 20px;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
.stages__working::before {
    content: counter(num); 
    counter-increment: num;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -23px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #95E1E1;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.stages__working::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: -2%;
    background-color: #95E1E1;
    width: 5px;
    margin-top: 0;
    height: 85px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.end::after {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<ol class="stages">
    <li class="stages__working">Знакомство с клиентом, описание заказа</li>
    <li class="stages__working">Мы скидываем примеры своих работ, также ссылку на 
        инстаграм</li>
    <li class="stages__working">Отработка заказа, исходные данные от клиента и все это 
        отправляем дизайнеру</li>
    <li class="stages__working">Макет от дизайнера клиенту даем на утверждение, 
        обсуждаем детали рисунка, вносим изменения и корректировки.</li>
    <li class="stages__working">Подбор футболки, толстовки: цвет, размер, ткань, 
        производителя. Делаем замеры в случае необходимости.</li>
    <li class="stages__working">Макет готов, футболка тоже, запускаем в 
        производство</li>
    <li class="stages__working">Распечатываем рисунок на бумаге, выясняем место 
        расположения рисунка</li>
    <li class="stages__working">Заказ выполнен, упаковываем, кладем инструкцию, планер в 
        подарок</li>
    <li class="stages__working end">Доставка по индрайверу или самовывоз</li>
</ol>
```

must be done as in the photo
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4rjD.png)

I don't have any idea how to implement it

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I add CSS for left & right alignment, you have to use "nth:child(odd) & nth:child(even)" using this you can easily set your Timeline Layout.

```css
        .stages{
    list-style-type: none; 
    counter-reset: num;
    margin: 0 0 0 45px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.stages__working{
    position: relative; 
    margin: 0 ;
    padding: 8px 0 45px 20px;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
.stages__working::before {
    content: counter(num); 
    counter-increment: num;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -23px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #95E1E1;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.stages__working::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: -2%;
    background-color: #95E1E1;
    width: 5px;
    margin-top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.end::after {
    display: none;
}

/*add this CSS*/


ol.stages {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ol.stages li.stages__working {
    max-width: 185px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

ol.stages li.stages__working:nth-child(even) {
    margin: 0 0 0 auto;
}

ol.stages li.stages__working:nth-child(odd)::after {
    left: unset;
    right: -50px;
    top: 30px;
}

ol.stages li.stages__working:nth-child(odd)::before {
    left: unset;
    right: -62px;
}

ol.stages li.stages__working:nth-child(even)::after {
    right: unset;
    left: -45px;
    top: 0;
}

ol.stages li.stages__working:nth-child(even)::before {
    right: unset;
    left: -57px;
}
```

```html
<ol class="stages">
    <li class="stages__working">Знакомство с клиентом, описание заказа</li>
    <li class="stages__working">Мы скидываем примеры своих работ, также ссылку на 
        инстаграм</li>
    <li class="stages__working">Отработка заказа, исходные данные от клиента и все это 
        отправляем дизайнеру</li>
    <li class="stages__working">Макет от дизайнера клиенту даем на утверждение, 
        обсуждаем детали рисунка, вносим изменения и корректировки.</li>
    <li class="stages__working">Подбор футболки, толстовки: цвет, размер, ткань, 
        производителя. Делаем замеры в случае необходимости.</li>
    <li class="stages__working">Макет готов, футболка тоже, запускаем в 
        производство</li>
    <li class="stages__working">Распечатываем рисунок на бумаге, выясняем место 
        расположения рисунка</li>
    <li class="stages__working">Заказ выполнен, упаковываем, кладем инструкцию, планер в 
        подарок</li>
    <li class="stages__working end">Доставка по индрайверу или самовывоз</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

with using `nth-child(odd)` you can do it?
*and this is responsive ;)*

```css
.stages{
    list-style-type: none; 
    counter-reset: num;
    margin: 0 45px 0 50% ;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
    max-width:100%;
    position: relative;
}
.stages__working{
    position: relative; 
    margin: 0 ;
    padding: 8px 30px 45px 30px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    width:500px;
    max-width:100%;
}
.stages__working::before {
    content: counter(num); 
    counter-increment: num;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -13px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #95E1E1;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.stages__working::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #95E1E1;
    width: 5px;
    margin-top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.stages__working:nth-child(odd){
  text-align: right;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.stages__working:nth-child(odd):after{
  left: 100%;
}

.stages__working:nth-child(odd):before{
  left: calc(100% - 13px);
}
.end::after {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<ol class="stages">
    <li class="stages__working">Знакомство с клиентом, описание заказа</li>
    <li class="stages__working">Мы скидываем примеры своих работ, также ссылку на 
        инстаграм</li>
    <li class="stages__working">Отработка заказа, исходные данные от клиента и все это 
        отправляем дизайнеру</li>
    <li class="stages__working">Макет от дизайнера клиенту даем на утверждение, 
        обсуждаем детали рисунка, вносим изменения и корректировки.</li>
    <li class="stages__working">Подбор футболки, толстовки: цвет, размер, ткань, 
        производителя. Делаем замеры в случае необходимости.</li>
    <li class="stages__working">Макет готов, футболка тоже, запускаем в 
        производство</li>
    <li class="stages__working">Распечатываем рисунок на бумаге, выясняем место 
        расположения рисунка</li>
    <li class="stages__working">Заказ выполнен, упаковываем, кладем инструкцию, планер в 
        подарок</li>
    <li class="stages__working end">Доставка по индрайверу или самовывоз</li>
</ol>
```